# React app created with Vite refreshing problem on IIS server. if i go to a specific route and then refresh the page it shows me HTTP Error 500

Tags: reactjs, iis, react-router, vite

I created a react app with vite and now I hosted it on local IIS server. If I go to homepage it working fine and all routing are working fine, but after going to another route and trying to refresh the page it gives me this error:

> ```
> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
> Detailed Error Information:
> Module       IIS Web Core
> Notification     Unknown
> Handler      Not yet determined
> Error Code       0x8007000d
> Config Error     Configuration file '\\?\D:\General Store\dist\web.config' does not contain a root <configuration> tag
> Config File      \\?\D:\General Store\dist\web.config
> Requested URL    http://192.168.0.6:86/
> Physical Path    
> Logon Method     Not yet determined
> Logon User       Not yet determined
>
> Config Source:
>     1: <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
>     2:   <match url=".*" />
> ```

How can I solve this problem?

I tried to add `web.config` and added this code to it:

```xml
<code>
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration>
       <system.webServer>
           <rewrite>
               <rules>
                   <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                       <match url=".*" />
                       <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                           <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                       </conditions>
                       <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                   </rule>
               </rules>
           </rewrite>
       </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
</code>
```

I also tried `.htaccess` and `_redirects` solution but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Take a read through the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to see if there's a section relevant to your server/hosting service for what needs to be configured correctly.

Comment: this web.config file is working in react app if i created with create-react-app command. but not working if i create with vite-react command.

Comment: CRA handles a lot of the webpack config. Is that something you have separate when using Vite that you can share?

Comment: No, i did not separate anything in webpack config.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you need to make sure to install :
**Download URL Rewrite Module 2.1** : [Link Here](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

***and Follow the configuration :***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, You made my day. it solved my problem. URL Rewrite Module was not installed in my system.